# Android: Custom triangle icon in spinner using android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

how to customize the icon in the right side of the spinner. As you can see in the image below inside of the red circle there is a black circle the data inside of that spinner came from database. Is there a way to remove it? if none, how to change it?

[image]

For the code, I just add this in my styles.xml and then that black circles appeared also.

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>

    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">#909090</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerItem.DropDownItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textColor">#909090</item>
    </style>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I already have answer.

instead of this code

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>

    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">#909090</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerItem.DropDownItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textColor">#909090</item>
    </style>
```

I made it like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">#909090</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Theme.MyListView</item>


</style>



<style name="Theme.MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView">

</style>
```